# OpenSSL 3.0 on Unbuntu 22.10: HMAC using SHA1 not found?

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

I'm familiar with Linux but not Ubuntu. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$ grep ^PRETTY_NAME /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.10"
$ openssl list -digest-algorithms | grep -iw sha1
  RSA-SHA1 => SHA1
  RSA-SHA1-2 => RSA-SHA1
  MD5-SHA1
  SHA1
  sha1WithRSAEncryption => SHA1
  ssl3-sha1 => SHA1
  { 1.3.14.3.2.26, SHA-1, SHA1, SSL3-SHA1 } @ default
  MD5-SHA1 @ default
$ cat test.c
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

int main() {
    EVP_MAC *mac = EVP_MAC_fetch(NULL, "SHA1", NULL);
    if (mac == NULL) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    EVP_MAC_free(mac);
    return 0;
}
$ cc -o test -Wall test.c -lcrypto 
$ ./test
40F7F862667F0000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:../crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c:373:Global default library context, Algorithm (SHA1 : 94), Properties (<null>)
```

It seems like OpenSSL is not able to find the "SHA1" HMAC algorithm.

I thought I was following the example [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_MAC_fetch.html) but obviously I'm missing something.

Comment: SHA1 is not a MAC algorithm,  it is a hash/digest algorithm. HMAC is a MAC algorithm that takes a _hash_ name, such as SHA1, as a _parameter_. The example on the man page as run uses the (different) MAC _algorithm_ CMAC with _parameter_ cipher=aes-128-cbc; you want to use _algorithm_ HMAC with _parameter_ digest=SHA1 .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @dave_thompson_085 for the answer.

Now this works:

```c
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

int main() {
    EVP_MAC *mac;
    EVP_MAC_CTX *ctx;
    OSSL_PARAM params[2];

    params[0] = OSSL_PARAM_construct_utf8_string("digest", "SHA1", 0);
    params[1] = OSSL_PARAM_construct_end();
    if ((mac = EVP_MAC_fetch(NULL, "HMAC", NULL)) == NULL)
        goto fail;
    if ((ctx = EVP_MAC_CTX_new(mac)) == NULL)
        goto fail;
    if (!EVP_MAC_init(ctx, (unsigned char *)"secret", 6, params))
        goto fail;
    EVP_MAC_CTX_free(ctx);
    EVP_MAC_free(mac);
    return 0;

fail:
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    return 1;
}
```